# Boost 12V to 24V, high current output

Tags: power-supply, batteries, boost

There are a lot of dc-dc boost modules that step 12V to 24V but are limited to low current. Is there a reason why stepping up voltage, while keeping the current high is not available?

In my case, I have a solenoid that works at 24V. I have a 12V 24Ah battery and the solenoid requires 24V, ~25A. Is there a solution to boost my supply?

Comment: Conservation of energy. A boost converter is basically changing the balance between current and voltage. You can achieve high current by charging capacitor that is rated for such currents to create a high current pulse.

Comment: The peak current from my battery is 420A. How do I go about building a boost converter for this?

Comment: Your solenoid takes 25 amps from a 24 volt DC supply. That's a power of 600 watts. Can you confirm this and, also how long you expect the battery to last when powering the solenoid continuously before requiring a re-charge? I estimate about 10 to 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes, thats right. The solenoid will be on for about 5s in a minute. The battery life is not an issue.

Comment: @KarthikNishanth maybe take a look at this. It will help you. https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-boost-calc

Comment: @Bradman175 LOL that isn't man enough for what he needs by a mile. The IRFD110 has a continuous current of ermm... basically zero compared to what the OP needs (about 60 amps).

Comment: @Andyaka I was afraid the components they suggested would be pretty weak. It's to give the OP an idea, which I should've specified...

Comment: To answer the first question, the usual reason why anything is not available is there is no (sufficiently large) market for it

Comment: And the reason there is no (sufficiently large) market for it is because it has a strongly negative cost/benefit ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need MOMENTARY activation of the solenoid?  Or CONTINUOUS activation? You could do some circuit tricks with switching super-caps if you need only momentary. But a boost converter for 25A will be large and expensive. May be better to use a 12V solenoid or add another 12V battery to create 24V.

Comment: I would need momentary activation.

Comment: Then do as the man says and add another battery.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @RichardCrowley, using a second 12v battery in series with the first would be more robust. Since I couldn't post a diagram in a comment, here it is as a separate answer. Click image to make full-size.

[image: 600W Solenoid Driver]

Some liberty was taken in assuming characteristics for the solenoid and control requirements. This isn't super-fast, but it is simple and low-cost.

- Two HAT1072H power PMOSFETs were paralleled to distribute heat over a greater surface area. This PMOS was arbitrarily chosen for it's very low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ of \$3.6m\Omega\$ but any power device should work. A down-side to this particular device is it's \$V_{GSS}\$ of -20v. This means that pulling the gates to ground from +24v source would be problematic.
- D2 12v zener diode drops 12 of these volts, so that the gates only see -12v or so (red trace.) Note that for several microseconds, D2 conducts substantial current discharging the gate capacitance. It cannot do this repetively, or it will overheat.
- Likewise, R3 will take ~100uS to re-charge the PMOS gates after turn-off, during which time the PMOS will be dissipating large amounts of power. Bottom line is, the duty cycle must be very low. No cycling it multiple times per second.
- About 22v (considering losses) is switched into the solenoid (green trace) for about 24A of drive current.
- Steady-state losses of the PMOS should be about half a watt each when on.
- After switching off, D1 conducts the back-emf from the solenoid for about 10mS, causing the voltage to go below ground to about -1v. Without D1, the PMOS would certainly be destroyed. No digital logic can be connected to the solenoid either - the -1v will likely cause latch-up.
- D1 will also *slow down* the *mechanical release* of the solenoid. If this is a problem, research [solenoid clamps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=solenoid+clamp).
- Q1 is a high-current NPN, driven very hard (Ib=100mA) to squeeze as much switch-on speed from the PMOS as possible. This drive can be relaxed, at the cost of increased switching loss.

Comment: I liked your use of informative annotations on the circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a cheap 12 V -> 120 VAC inverter of the type people use to run their plug-in appliances off of a car/boat/RV battery, and then use a 120 VAC->24 V transformer/power supply.  This is bulky and expensive compared to something made for your purpose, but can be basically plug-and-play.

In general, it would be better to avoid the high voltage step if all you need to do is drive a solenoid, but assuming you are in some mobile application, it might be useful to have 120 VAC for other reasons.